# Gas Limit Drops to Zero for Internal Transaction

Tags: solidity, etherscan, solidity-0.8.x

I've deployed a contract to Rinkeby involving a few different interfaces I've written. This result in a fair number of transactions occurring behind the scenes with different contracts. There is a particular transaction that somewhat intermittently causes a reversion on Rinkeby and I can't sort out why. For reference I am maxing out the gas limit on Rinkeby just to test the functionality first, so 'running out of gas' shouldn't be an issue here.

The one common thread in all the failures is that the gas_limit suddenly drops to zero in the Rinkey internal tx logs like:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x565a7e392596f547364dc31b0da021f8626235bfe5eeb6d04d27c8115b31fea4#internal the example here.

A similar transaction I executed was successful and produced 33 internal transactions
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd3f3e2b56e74c78c3128fcbea68385876686d43515ba454864854220bb7a1e7b#internal

I'm testing a bunch of different permutations of ways to run this transaction looking for what triggers it. But my own issues aside --> what does it mean when the gas limit drops to zero like this? Successful transactions do not show a zero-ing out of the gas limit.

Comment: My guess is that it simply reverts due to code issues. Therefore the gas values look strange, but you shouldn't be really looking at those

Comment: It’s definitely possible. The hardest part of testing is that I do a bunch of swaps on uniswap and liquidity pools on testnets are terrible - so what happens is my tests pass on a local fork of mainnet and then fail on rinkeby - I can run nearly identical code on the fork and it works and then fails on rinkeby. :(

Comment: Do you have the contract source? From geth trace https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x565a7e392596f547364dc31b0da021f8626235bfe5eeb6d04d27c8115b31fea4&type=gethtrace2 a calls has an internal error.

Comment: thanks @Ismael i used the etherscan plugin to push the code there, so it's on etherscan - i'll need to figure out how to match things up here - if you have any pushes in the right direction it'd be appreciated

Comment: The contract that fails https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd0b565c1869f14e73dd7619d21e479f2f6129bf0 doesn't have source verified.